# Bug on rpart.plot predict when rules set to TRUE?

Tags: r, decision-tree

I was reading the [rpart.plot document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart.plot/rpart.plot.pdf) and was interested in using the `rules` parameter on `rpart.predict`. However, when following the example I get an error message. Am I missing something?

[image]

Update: this is my `sessionInfo()`:

[image]

Comment: When i run your code,  i get no error nor error message.

Comment: @G5W are you using the same rpart.plot version by any chance?

Comment: I am using:   rpart.plot_3.1.1   -    rpart_4.1.16 , the same as you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `rpart.rules` function:

> Print an rpart model as a set of rules.

Here a reproducible example:

```r
library(rpart.plot)
data(ptitanic)
model <- rpart(survived ~., data = ptitanic, cp =0.02)
rpart.rules(model)
#>  survived                                             
#>      0.05 when sex is   male & age <  9.5 & sibsp >= 3
#>      0.17 when sex is   male & age >= 9.5             
#>      0.73 when sex is female                          
#>      0.89 when sex is   male & age <  9.5 & sibsp <  3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>